# Enemy logic errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm following a tutorial into making a game in Unity, and I've encountered a peculiar problem with my JavaScript/UnityScript:

```js
#pragma strict

var Health = 100;

function ApplyDamage (TheDamage : int)
{
    Health -= TheDamage;

    if(Health <= 0)
    {
        Dead();
   }
}

function Dead()
{
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

That is my script for the enemy game object, however, despite me having logic for a melee system where you have to click him twice and he dies, it doesn't work, and whenever my player character walks into the enemy it is destroyed automatically without clicks.

I'll post my melee system here too:

```js
#pragma strict

var TheDamage : int = 50;
var Distance : float;
var MaxDistance : float = 1.5;

function Update () 
{
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))

         var hit : RaycastHit;
         if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
         {
             Distance = hit.distance;
             if (Distance < MaxDistance)
             (
                  hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", TheDamage, SendMessageOptions. DontRequireReceiver)     
             );

   }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? It seems like a random error.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted for your melee system is missing braces `{}` for the first if statement, causing it to only execute `var hit : RaycastHit;` when the mouse is clicked, and execute the rest of the body every time Update is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a problem. You are not actually using the `if` statement correctly. This is because you didn't use `{}`. I will post how your code is being interpreted below:

```
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
 {
    var hit : RaycastHit;
 }

 if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
 {
     Distance = hit.distance;
     if (Distance < MaxDistance)
     {
        hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", TheDamage, SendMessageOptions. DontRequireReceiver);    
     }                 
 }
```

Obviously that is not what you intended. Remember if you don't put the brackets then only the line directly after the `if` will execute when the if condition is met, the rest will execute independently of that if.

#### Solution

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
    {
        Distance = hit.distance;

        // Intentionally left the brackets out of this if to show you.
        if(Distance < MaxDistance) 
           hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", TheDamage, SendMessageOptions. DontRequireReceiver);     
    }
}
```

So I intentionally left out the brackets on that inside `if` to show you how to use it without brackets. If you are unsure, just add brackets, it will make your code cleaner and easier to understand and you will avoid bugs.